# Remove the first two digits from year - Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with year, term as fields. The current values in the table is in this format:

```
year | term
------------
2006 | S1
2007 | S2
2009 | S1
2010 | S2
```

I am using the following code to no success:

```
select concat (replace(term, 'S', 's'), year) as test from semesters;
```

I get the following results:

```
Test
----
s12006
s22007
s12009
s12010
```

I want to run a query where I will get the result in this format:

```
Test
-----
s106
s207
s109
s210
```

Please give me some pointer on how to achieve this in postgresql. Thanks

Comment: substring comes to mind.

Comment: `date_format(year,'%y')` `select concat (replace(term, 'S', 's'), date_format(year,'%y') as test from semesters;`

Comment: RIGHT( year, 2) should also work if you know all your years are exactly 4 length

Comment: Stop using string formats on dates use date functions to work with dates.

Comment: It's not a date, it's an integer. At least from the info we were given. Your point stands though.

Comment: True that.... I don't know why was going though my mind thinking it was a date...

Comment: This one uses the 2 least significant digits of the year:`select concat (replace(term, 'S', 's'), year % 100) as test from semesters;`.

Comment: its an integer and thats why the date isnt working. Any other solutions ?

Answer (score 1):

```
select lower(term) || to_char(to_date(year::text, 'YYYY'), 'YY');
```

Answer (score 0):

You just want the last two characters from the year, so:

```
select concat(replace(term, 'S', 's'), right(year, 2)) as test
from semesters;
```

Or, if you want to be fancy, use `overlay()`:

```
select overlay(year placing lower(term) from 1 for 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me eventually:

```
 select cast( concat (SUBSTR(cast (year as text), 3,4), 
 replace(term, 'S', 's')) as char(4)) as test from semesters;
```